# vmware player bridged does not work when on vpn

Tags: networking, security, vmware, vpn

The problem I am having now is I vpn off from my job to a vpn provider. I then load my kali linux vm and connect to the vpn my security labs. I can run scans, enumerations etc. The problem is when I go to run a bind_tcp /reverse shell whatever it will never open the session and with wireshark I start to notice tcp retransmission packets. The very weird thing about this is if I do the exact same thing from home it works fine no problems. When I am at home bridged network in my vm works fine. When I am vpned off at work it does not work I have to change it to nat to even get internet access in my vm.

I am using vmware player on ubuntu 12.04 lts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm seeing exactly the same issue. But I solved the folowing issue:

***Issue***: Network Bridge keeps disconnecting on a vm Ubuntu 12.04 64bit using VMWare.

***Workaround***: Modifying the following 2 files to have an entry with the same hostname (in my case `/etc/hostname` was different from the one in `/etc/hosts`).

In `/etc/hosts`:

```
:
127.0.1.1       %YOUR_VM_HOSTNAME%
:
```

In `/etc/hostname`:

```
%YOUR_VM_HOSTNAME%
```